# Kendo button(k-button) is not triggering on click event Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a K-button on kendo grid, when onclick of that button I am expecting to redirect to controller with parameters, but onclick of that button it is not doing anything, even I kept debugger but still no go, it is not at all triggering am I missing anything let me know, I have tried both `"` and `'` along with different format like `$(".info").on('click', function ()`

**CODE**

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-template">

 #if(ResultFormatID != 3) { #

<input type="checkbox" #= data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\"/>
# } else { #
<input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Preview" />
# } #
</script>

$('.info').click(function() {
        debugger;
        var row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var item = Grid.dataItem(row);
        window.location.href = '/Login/FreeText?profileID=' + rowIDs + '&amp;billid=' + billID;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
<a class="info k-button" >Preview</a>

$(document).one('click', '.info', function () { 
    console.log("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked :), may i know what I was doing wrong or if not wrong, why it wasn't working except other buttons(which is outside the grid) works fine with the same format ?? any idea, so that in future I can keep in mind